# automatic scaling

Tags: android, image, scaling

Does android want that we put different version of an image (for different dpi) to avoid resizing-artifact because their scaling algorithm is not quality-efficient (to be fast i think) ?

But anyway, it's obvious that android will scale all image just for maybe some pixels, so, resizing-artifact does ONLY appear when we do a big resizing ?

Through this questions , i want to understand the utility of putting different size of image and why we don't just put a big resolution image and let android scale down every time.
(I have also a suppositon that i want to confirm, maybe the algorithm take more time when the scale factor is important)

Thx.

Comment: Scaling the image at runtime may be memory consuming . Possibly that might be reason I am not sure though

Comment: If you use **small** pictures and pretend to scale them **up**, then you'll get **pixellated** images, which are usually very ugly. Otherwise, using **big** images and letting them be scaled **down** will produce **interpolated** (averaged) pictures, which usually offer a better quality. But this happens in every image editor as well. And it's very logical, if you figure out how an image will be scaled by the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the highest quality images in your app, your app consumes more memory (RAM) and if the device has less memory than your app freezes more frequently. This will not provide a good user experience as we all want that our app should be smooth in performance.

Besides all, I had also tested that if we put larger images and try to display them, Sometimes the app also crashed by giving an error of out of memory.

If you want to only place one image in your app to reduce the size of your app than I advise you to do it with .svg images. These images are scalable and the CPU does not have to do extra processing to display them.

I hope it will help you. Thank You

Comment: It's not the answer that i excepted but it's a other solution to the problem, thx !